# SQL Server query for name value pairs

Tags: sql, sql-server, xml, t-sql, for-xml

I'm new at creating an XML file using SQL server.  I have 2 tables; 1 for people and the other with default settings for them.

**Person** table:

```
ABC   
DEF
```

**Settings** table:

```
Code           name                 value           
-----------------------------------------
Hair           Hair color           Brown                  
Hair           Texture              Curly             
Shoes          Shoe size            6            
Shoes          Shoe color           White
```

How can I create an name value pair that looks like this? When I try to get the settings, I received an error about multiple records:

```
<PersonData>
  <Person>ABC</Person>
    <DefaultSettings>
      <Code>Hair</Code>
      <settings>
        <name>Hair color</name>
        <value>Brown</value>
      </settings>
      <settings>
        <name>Texture</name>
        <value>Curly</value>
      </settings>
      <Code>Shoes</Code>
      <settings>
        <name>Shoe size</name>
        <value>6</value>
      </settings>
      <settings>
        <name>Shoe color</name>
        <value>White</value>
      </settings>
    </DefaultSettings>
  </Person>
  <Person>DEF</Person>
    <DefaultSettings>
      <Code>Hair</Code>
      <settings>
        <name>Hair color</name>
        <value>Brown</value>
      </settings>
      <settings>
        <name>Texture</name>
        <value>Curly</value>
      </settings>
      <Code>Shoes</Code>
      <settings>
        <name>Shoe size</name>
        <value>6</value>
      </settings>
      <settings>
        <name>Shoe color</name>
        <value>White</value>
      </settings>
    </DefaultSettings>
  </Person>
</PersonData>
```

Comment: have you google 'For XML Sql Server'? Show some code that you tried and tell why it didnt work

Comment: This makes no sense. All people get the same settings? A setting code represents multiple values?

Comment: You XML is not valid. You are closing the `<Person>` tag behind the person's name and then again after the closing `/<DefaultSettings>`. Please repair your expected output...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As told in my comment your given XML is not valid. The following query comes close to the output you requested. Hoping, that my magic glass bulb is still working:

```
DECLARE @personTable TABLE(ID INT IDENTITY, Name VARCHAR(100));
INSERT INTO @personTable VALUES
('ABC'),('DEF');

DECLARE @defaultSettings TABLE(Code VARCHAR(100),name VARCHAR(100),value VARCHAR(100));           
INSERT INTO @defaultSettings VALUES 
 ('Hair','Hair color','Brown')                  
,('Hair','Texture','Curly')        
,('Shoes','Shoe size','6')            
,('Shoes','Shoe color','White');

SELECT pd.ID AS [Person/@id]
      ,pd.Name AS [Person/@name]
      ,(
        SELECT ds.Code
              ,(
                SELECT ds2.name
                      ,ds2.value
                FROM @defaultSettings AS ds2
                WHERE ds.Code=ds2.Code
                FOR XML PATH('settings'),TYPE
               )
        FROM @defaultSettings AS ds
        GROUP BY ds.Code
        FOR XML PATH(''),TYPE
       ) AS [Person/DefaultSettings]
FROM @personTable AS pd
FOR XML PATH(''),ROOT ('PersonData')
```

The result

```
<PersonData>
  <Person id="1" name="ABC">
    <DefaultSettings>
      <Code>Hair</Code>
      <settings>
        <name>Hair color</name>
        <value>Brown</value>
      </settings>
      <settings>
        <name>Texture</name>
        <value>Curly</value>
      </settings>
      <Code>Shoes</Code>
      <settings>
        <name>Shoe size</name>
        <value>6</value>
      </settings>
      <settings>
        <name>Shoe color</name>
        <value>White</value>
      </settings>
    </DefaultSettings>
  </Person>
  <Person id="2" name="DEF">
    <DefaultSettings>
      <Code>Hair</Code>
      <settings>
        <name>Hair color</name>
        <value>Brown</value>
      </settings>
      <settings>
        <name>Texture</name>
        <value>Curly</value>
      </settings>
      <Code>Shoes</Code>
      <settings>
        <name>Shoe size</name>
        <value>6</value>
      </settings>
      <settings>
        <name>Shoe color</name>
        <value>White</value>
      </settings>
    </DefaultSettings>
  </Person>
</PersonData>
```

Comment: Thank you, Shnugo!  i will try that.  I know the data doesn't make sense but it's a mock up to be discrete.  I have to convert data to the vendor's specs.  This is a section of the total PersonData.  Can the query be incorporated into another query?

Comment: @okidog The query is fully *ad-hoc* and therefore easy to incorporate into another query. Think of the whole expression to return one scalar value. Just put paranthesis around it and add it to the column list of a select.

Comment: It works great!  I just need to figure out how to get rid of the namespaces.  Thank you so much!

Comment: Sorry!  Appreciate your guidance on this.